# Consulta like con parámetros en python

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
query.exec_("SELECT id,fecha,hora,tipo,lugar FROM eventos ORDER BY fecha_orden DESC,hora ")
```

sobre python3 y sqlite3 , la muestro sobre un QTableWidget. Funciona bien

Ahora quiero mostrar la consulta  con el comodín % usando like. Para resolver consultas del tipo:

```
SELECT id,fecha,hora,tipo,lugar FROM eventos WHERE  fecha LIKE '%12-2020'
```

Lo he intentado con :

```
query.exec_("SELECT id,fecha,hora,tipo,lugar FROM eventos WHERE  fecha  LIKE", "%"+fecha+"%" )
```

siendo fecha = '12-2020' el parámetro,y obtengo:

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
> exec_(self, str): too many arguments
> exec_(self): too many arguments

He usado distintas variantes del código y obtengo respuestas parecidas. ¿ Pueden ayudarme ?

Comment: El error es claro. La función espera solo 2 argumentos: self (automático) y una cadena. Estás pasando 3 argumentos: self (automático) y 2 cadenas.

Comment: leo en la documentación de Python que query.exec_ (sql,[,params]), interpreto "%"+Fecha+"%" como un string ¿No es así?

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto el error estaba en la sintaxis:
cursor.execute("SELECT id,fecha,hora,tipo,lugar FROM eventos WHERE  fecha  LIKE ? ", ('%'+fecha,) )